# Trigger the React-Bootstrap Input Component Validation Programmatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm quite new to react so this may be a pretty easy thing to do. I am currently working on a Modal component (from ReactBootstrap) and I am using a react-bootstrap Input component inside the Modal dialog component, with `type=email`. This, when inside a `<form>` element and the form is submitted will trigger validation and a popoup type message is displayed on top of the input component if validation fails. However, I am not using this component inside a `<form>` element and want to trigger this when clicking on a button. This is a working piece of code I have that represents the issue:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
var ModalTrigger = ReactBootstrap.ModalTrigger;
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var Input = ReactBootstrap.Input;

var TheModal = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function() {
        // I want to trigger the email input validation here
        // via this.refs.theInput
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Modal {...this.props} title="Modal Title" animation={true} closeButton={false}>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <Input ref="theInput" type="email" label="Email Address" defaultValue="Enter email" />
                </div>

                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</Button>
                    <Button bsStyle="danger" onClick={this.props.onRequestHide}>Close</Button>

                </div>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ModalTrigger modal={<TheModal />}>
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Trigger Modal</Button>
                </ModalTrigger>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render( <App />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the `getValue()` function directly on the Input.

`this.refs.theInput.getValue()` should return your `theInput` value.

Don't use `getDOMNode()` if you possibly can avoid it, because it assumes the underlying DOM implementation won't change in future versions.  Look at the react-bootstrap Input.jsx file for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` event is wired up to `handleSubmit()`, that looks OK.

Does accessing the email value via `this.refs.theInput.getDOMNode().value` not work in `handleSubmit()`?

If so, I wonder if ReactBootstrap's `<Input>` is wrapping the native DOM `<input>` in some other elements; you might have to navigate the DOM tree in order to get to the actual `<input>` to grab the email value from.

Answer (score 0):

Like Peter mentioned, I had to traverse the object pretty far.

In my component's render function;

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <Input ref='gameTitle' type='text' buttonAfter={<Button type="submit">Save</Button>} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

In my handleSubmit function;

```
handleSubmit: function() {
  console.log(this.refs.gameTitle.refs.input.getDOMNode().value);
}
```